# Android studio позаменяла многие классы какой то ерундой, в вопросе скрины

Tags: android-studio

Андроид студио глюканула и позаменяла многие классы в рабочем проекте какой то ерундой вот скрины содержимого вместо классов http://prntscr.com/p83iqn, http://prntscr.com/p83k2w.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем сами файлы не пострадали, если все проверить через папку все норм. Решение сначало обновил студию, затем File->Invalidate caches. Cнова перезапуск вроде все работает, но почему то в Retrofit2 все связи потерялись между классами и интерфейсами, остальное все норм.